# Uploading large files to dropbox in chunks using dropnet

Tags: dropbox, dropnet

I recently tried Dropnet API to connect dropbox app in my C# project. Everything works fine, but I want to upload large files through chunkupload request.

```
public void FileUpload()
{
    string file = @"E:\threading.pdf";
    int chunkSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;

    var buffer = new byte[chunkSize];
    int bytesRead;
    int chunkCount = 0;
    ChunkedUpload chunkupload = null;            

    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        while ((bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            chunkCount++;
            if (chunkCount == 1)
            {
                chunkupload = client.StartChunkedUpload(buffer);
            }
            else
            {
                chunkupload = client.AppendChunkedUpload(chunkupload, buffer);
            }
        }
    }
    var metadata = client.CommitChunkedUpload(chunkupload, "/threading.pdf", true);           
 }
```

The file size is 1.6 MB.  When i Checked, first chunk contains 1 MB and second one contains 0.6MB but  only 13 bytes data gets uploaded in each chunk. Could anyone point out problem here.

Comment: It seems you'll need another buffer with size of bytesRead as dropnet api doesn't take the length parameters, you'll end up with garbage at the end of the buffer for some of the chunks.

Answer (score 1):

Update RestSharp to 104.4.0 to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

There's a problem with RestSharper that is used by Dropnet.
Each uploaded chunk uploads exactly 13 bytes
'System.Byte[]'

The problem is that array of bytes is converted to string using method 'AddParameter'.

I didn't dig too much. I'm trying to use UploadFile method.